# Visual Studio Code removes the '?>' bracket for the PHP tag

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I am having a problem with VS Code. The editor's current configuration removes PHP's closing tag. The closing tag I am referencing looks like this: **`?>`**

##### The steps I use to reproduce the issue are simple

1. **I create a file: `content.php`**
2. **I add the following code:**

   ```
     <?php  
        echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['login']."<br />";           
     ?>
   ```
3. **Then I save the file**
   To save I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and the code closing element disappears, and I end up with the following code:**

   ```
      <?php
          echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['login']."<br />";
   ```

---

I doubt the above steps will recreate the issue in most editors, as it is likely a configuration issue that's causing the problem.

Has anyone had a similar problem? &/or does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When you write **PHP**, and your PHP document is only **PHP**, the PHP documentation recommends leaving out the PHP closing bracket, in other words: VSCode is using auto-format language features to preform the right type of formatting/linting in this situation. You can read the PHP Documentation for yourself Here:*

---

##### [PHP: Opening & Closing Brackets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

---

> *In addition to the information above, it is important to note the Visual Studio Code implements a PHP-Linter *"out of the box"*. I most certainly ***DO NOT ADVISE TURNING THE LINTER OFF**, however, the choice is yours. Turning the linter off can be done by configuring the setting below in your user or workspace **`settings.json` File**.**

---

```
  
  /* FILE: "./.vscode/settings.json"s
   * LINTING ON: "Set to "true" to enable to linter."
   * LINTING OFF: "Set to "false" to disable the linter."  */

  {
    "php.validate.enable": false
  }
```

---

> *Another option you have, which I find useful for all sorts of different configurations, is to set when the Linter executes. This can be done by configuring the setting below in your user or workspace **`settings.json` File**.*

---

```
  // "./.vscode/settings.json"

  {
    "php.validate.run": "onSave"
  }
```

---